# prevent to crash node js after uncaughtExceptions

Tags: node.js

i have written one middle-ware for handling uncaughtExceptions which is working fine but after that server will crashed.
how do i prevent to crash it?

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const winston = require("winston");
const app = express();

//Logging is responsible to log and display errors
require('./startup/logging')();
//routes will contains all the routes list
require('./startup/routes')(app);

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port,() => winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}....`));
```

**logging.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const winston = require('winston');
// require('express-async-errors');

module.exports = function() {
  winston.handleExceptions(
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'uncaughtExceptions.log' })
  );

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    throw ex;
  });

  winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'error.log' });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#to-exit-or-not-to-exit) states,

> By default, winston will exit after logging an uncaughtException. If this is not the behavior you want, set exitOnError = false
>
> ```
> const logger = winston.createLogger({ exitOnError: false });
>
> //
> // or, like this:
> //
> logger.exitOnError = false;
> ```

It is generally considered a bad practice to not exit after an exception because the consequences are unpredictable. If only some of the exceptions are known to be tolerable, they can be specifically handled with a predicate:

```
const ignoreWarnings = err => !(err instanceof WarningError);

const logger = winston.createLogger({ exitOnError: ignoreWarnings });
```